# Wireless stops working on an MSI U180 netbook

Tags: 12.04, wireless

I'm having trouble with WiFi on my MSI U180 netbook using 12.04.

When I boot up the netbook, it will connect to my router, however, after a few minutes the WiFi will just stop working and not find or connect to any networks. The only way to get WiFi connectivity back is to reboot the netbook, however, the connection will again only last a few minutes. A wired connection works fine.

I have tried connecting to a different router and the same thing happens. My friend has the same OS and netbook and his works fine. Does anybody have any possible solutions?

Comment: Did your friend connect to the same wireless router(s)? If yes and it worked, try to boot both your netbooks from a Ubuntu live USB stick and see if they behave differently. If your netbook still won't work I would think it's a hardware problem. (Also connect only one at a time when testing.) If both works its probably a software problen...

Comment: my friend connected to a different router to me, it seems strange that the netbook initially connects and then just loses connection

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information.

Comment: Can you post the (possibly abridged and redacted) output of `dmesg` within a minute of the Wifi connection going down? Running [a Wifi diagnostics script](/q/425155) and supplying the output could be helpful too.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you have fixed this yet, but I had the same issue with my MSI U180 and in the "Edit connections" at the top go to your wireless and then choose your wireless AP and then go to IPV6 and set it to ignore and that fixed my issue with not being able to connect to wireless.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried the solution from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#Switching_between_drivers) and seems to be working, only having trouble with the "blacklist drivers" part.

Answer (score 1):

You could scan the wifi whit this command.

```
Rfkill list
Lspci
Lsmod wlan0
Sudo -dnkg -c wlan0
Firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

Press the <kbd>Fn</kbd> and <kbd>F11</kbd> buttons at the same time and the green Wi-Fi light should come on. Bingo--you're ready to go.